# Including header files in C++ (class definition and method implementation)

Tags: c++, header-files

I have already checked StackOverflow to find the solution to my problem, but I think I might be missing something. I am trying to define a class in a header file (.h) and implement its methods in a cpp file (.cpp), but it does not work.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Message.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Message *t = new (Message);

    t->display();

    return 0;
}
```

Message.h:

```
#ifndef MESSAGE_H_INCLUDED
#define MESSAGE_H_INCLUDED

class Message {
public:
    void display();
};

#endif // MESSAGE_H_INCLUDED
```

Message.cpp:

```
#include "Message.h"

void Message::display() {
    cout << "Hello!";
}
```

I don't understand why I keep getting the following error

```
undefined reference to 'Message::display()'
```

Comment: How do you compile this?

Comment: Your code is correct (aside from the memory leak).  Message.cpp is not getting linked - possibly not compiled.

Comment: I am using CodeBlocks (GNU GCC Compiler), with the flags: -O2, -ansi, -Wall and -pedantic

Comment: CodeBlocks will show you the compilation command being run.   Show *us*, please.

Comment: Thank you, I just fixed it. It was a compiling error, I solved it by going through Project->Properties...->Build Targets and then selecting all the files in the bottom section!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile this with the command `g++ -std=c++11 Message.cpp main.cpp`